# could not update iceauthority file /var/lib/gdm/.iceauthority

Tags: linux, centos6

I have centos 6.3 after my computer starts and reaches to login screen it shows the above warning and my keyboard and mouse stopped working also whole screen become black and I am unable to use any key.

Comment: I am having same issue please help

Comment: do you have your home directory encrypted using ecryptfs? If you do, and you recently changed your password, then you have to do the following: http://goshawknest.wordpress.com/2011/02/17/how-to-change-ecryptfs-home-cripted-filesystem-password-on-ubuntu-and-get-your-files-back/ Otherwise, it's as simple as booting into recovery and changing the ownership and chmod of the .ICEauthority file.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the file /var/lib/gdm/.ICEauthority and reboot.

Comment: You've better not delete the file, rather rename to stay able to roll it back. However the solution didn't work for me. The computer booted succesfully in my case, after the whole directory `/var/lib/gdm3` had been (re)moved. (It may have something todo with different GDM version. I use GDM3.)